# The symplectic group as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am currently trying to solve an exercise that is concerned with the symplectic group is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$ and the computation of its dimension.

[image]

I started as follows:

Define

$$
W:=GL(2n,\mathbb{R}) \\
V:=\{ A \in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}  \mid A^T=-A \}
$$

and consider the map

$$
g: W \to V, \ g(A)=A^T J A - J.  
$$

Consider the curve $\gamma: (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to W, \gamma(t)=A+tX$ where $\gamma(0)=A, \gamma'(0)=X$. Then we can show that

$$
g'(A)(X)
=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{dt}} |_{t=0} g(\gamma(t)) 
=A^T J X-(A^T J X)^T.  
$$

$A^T J$ is the product of invertible matrices and therefore invertible. Thus $g'(A): W \to V$ has full rank and is surjective. In particular we have $W \cap \text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})=g^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $W \cap \text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})=\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$  since $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $W$. Since $W$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$ the symplectic group $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$.

Let $d$ be the dimension of $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$. I am a bit confused about how to compute $d$. In the case of a linear mapping $f: U_1 \to U_2$ and finite-dimensional vectorspaces one could use the dimension formula $\text{dim}(U_1)=\text{dim} (\text{Im}(f))+\text{dim}(\text{ker}(f))$. But to my knowledge there is no such formula for manifolds. So I do not see how to compute $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a generalization of the formula from linear algebra exists.

Think of the linear case that you mentioned, with $f = \mathrm d g$ (the differential of the map $g$). Then you will see that all tangent spaces of ${\rm Sp}(2n,\mathbb R)$ (which are kernel of $\mathrm dg$) all have the same dimension (which will be the dimension of the manifold ${\rm Sp}(2n,\mathbb R)$).

More precisely, apply your linear algebra formula with $f=\mathrm dg$ at a point $A\in g^{-1}(\{0\}) = {\rm Sp}(2n,\mathbb R)$, and with $U_1=T_A{\rm GL}(2n,\mathbb R)$ (which you know the dimension of). Then $\ker f \simeq T_{A}{\rm Sp}(2n,\mathbb R)$ (which you want to compute the dimension of), and $\dim{\rm Im}\, f$ is the rank of $f$ which you have already shown to be constantly equal to $\dim V$.

All in all, you should get $$\dim{\rm Sp}(2n,\mathbb R) = \dim {\rm GL}(2n,\mathbb R)-\dim V = 
(2n)^2 - \frac{2n(2n-1)}2 = n(2n+1).$$

In general, it is a standard fact from differential geometry (I suggest to look at any differential geometry textbook in the chapter(s) about submanifolds, e.g. J.M. Lee ``Introduction to smooth manifolds'') that the fiber $g^{-1}(n)$ of $g:M\to N$ (for some $n\in N$) is a submanifold of dimension $$\dim M-\dim N$$ of $M$ whenever $n$ is a 'regular value' (i.e. whenever the differential map $\mathrm dg:T_mM\to T_nN$ is surjective for all $m\in g^{-1}(n)$).